# C# generics basic knowledge?

Tags: c#, generics

I have following two classes

```
public class CommandFetcher : ICommandFetcher
{
  private readonly Dictionary<TypeAndVersion, Type> _configuration;

  public CommandFetcher(Dictionary<TypeAndVersion, Type> configuration)
  {
      _configuration = configuration;
  }

    public ICommand FetchFrom(MessageEnvelope messageEnvelope)
    {
        TypeAndVersion typeAndVersion = new TypeAndVersion(messageEnvelope.MetaData.MessageType,
            messageEnvelope.MetaData.MessageTypeVersion);
        return (ICommand)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(messageEnvelope.MessageData, _configuration[typeAndVersion]);
    }
}
```

and

```
public class MessageDeserializer : IMessageDeserializer
{
    private readonly IDictionary<TypeAndVersion, Type> _configuration;

    public MessageDeserializer(IDictionary<TypeAndVersion, Type> configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IMessage Deserialize(string messageData, IMetaData metaData)
    {
        var typeAndVersion = new TypeAndVersion(metaData.MessageType, metaData.MessageTypeVersion);
        if (!_configuration.ContainsKey(typeAndVersion))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid version");
        return (IMessage) JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(messageData, _configuration[typeAndVersion]);
    }
}
```

i rewrite the  configuration part in both class 
but now i want to get that configuration from `MessageDeserializer` class into `CommandFetcher` class
how can i do it ?
Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

No idea if I am reading your question correctly...but it sounds like you are wanting to instantiate a CommandFetcher from within the MessageDesrializer?? If this is correct you could try making the Dictionary on the CommandFetcher an IDictionary instead of a Dictionary

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in your question:

1. You are not saying anything about the dependencies between the classes. Does one use the other?
2. You are not sharing what `configuration` actually is. Does each class need their own configuration?

So here is my guess: Your two classes actually use the same `_configuration`. In that case, this has nothing to do with generics. All you need to do is pass the same `Dictionary` to both object constructors.

Answer (score 1):

If you are attempting to make a single generic method that handles both those cases it would look something like this:

```
public class GenericDeserializer<T> : IGenericDeserializer
{
    private readonly IDictionary<TypeAndVersion, Type> _configuration;

    public GenericDeserializer(IDictionary<TypeAndVersion, Type> configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public T Deserialize(string messageData, IMetaData metaData)
    {
        var typeAndVersion = new TypeAndVersion(metaData.MessageType, metaData.MessageTypeVersion);
        if (!_configuration.ContainsKey(typeAndVersion))
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Invalid version");
        return (T)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(messageData, _configuration[typeAndVersion]);
    }
}
```

That said, you would need to normalize ICommand and IMessage as well as create a generic interface for ICommandFetcher and IMessageDeserializer.